# How can I load the openai api configuration through js in html?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, openai-api

I am trying to send a request through js in my html so that openai analyzes it and sends a response, but if in the js I put the following:

```
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");

const configuration = new Configuration({
apiKey: "sk-0000000000000ZXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

async function test() {
console("test")
const response = await openai.createCompletion("text-davinci-002", {
prompt: "hello",
temperature: 0.7,
max_tokens: 64,
top_p: 1,
frequency_penalty: 0,
presence_penalty: 0,
});
console.log(response)
}
test();
```

return console these error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at buttons.js:94:38
```

I have tried to install it with node.js and it works fine but I don't know how to make it work in my own html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the correct link that currently works:

`var url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/completions";`

and here is how the data should look like for question answering with davinchi-003 engine:

```js
var data = `{
              "model": "text-davinci-003",
              "prompt": "${prompt_text+question_out}",
              "temperature": 0.9,
              "max_tokens": 150,
              "top_p": 1,
              "frequency_penalty": 0.0,
              "presence_penalty": 0.6,
              "stop": [" Human:", " AI:"]
            }`;
```

here the `prompt_text` is the prompt text I sent o the engine and `question_out` is the question I want the engine to answer based on the prompt.

Answer (score 4):

It took me a little while to figure this out.

1. Go to https://beta.openai.com/playground and choose the settings you want.
2. Then, click "View code" in the top right.
3. Select "curl" as the code type you want to view.
4. Copy the "curl" code.
5. Go to: https://reqbin.com/req/javascript/c-wyuctivp/convert-curl-to-javascript.
6. Convert the code from "curl" to "javascript/AJAX". This will change it from "curl" to a javascript/AJAX XMLHttpRequest.

Use the javascript as you would normally. The code will console log the response. You can change that to use the response in some other way in your code.

Tested and working examples (You could just adjust these examples to meet your needs, but it may be best to create your own to get the exact results you want):

Regular prompt:

```js
let open_ai_response;

openai_test();

async function openai_test() {
  
  var url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/text-davinci-002/completions";

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", url);

  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer YOUR_OPEN_AI_KEY_GOES_HERE");

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        open_ai_response = xhr.responseText;
        console.log(open_ai_response);
     }};

  var data = `{
    "prompt": "YOUR TEXT HERE.",
    "temperature": 0.7,
    "max_tokens": 256,
    "top_p": 1,
    "frequency_penalty": 0.75,
    "presence_penalty": 0
  }`;

  xhr.send(data);
}
```

Using variables for the prompt:

```js
let open_ai_response;

openai_test();

async function openai_test() {
  
  var prompt_text = "YOUR TEXT HERE."
  var prompt_text2 = "MORE TEXT HERE."
  
  var url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/text-davinci-002/completions";

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", url);

  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer YOUR_OPEN_AI_KEY_GOES_HERE");

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        open_ai_response = xhr.responseText;
        console.log(open_ai_response);
     }};

  var data = `{
    "prompt": "${prompt_text + prompt_text2}",
    "temperature": 0.7,
    "max_tokens": 256,
    "top_p": 1,
    "frequency_penalty": 0.75,
    "presence_penalty": 0
  }`;

  xhr.send(data);
}
```

Comment: When I use the second version (using a variable for the prompt), it doesn't work. The API returns an error saying it could not parse the JSON. The same code when I use the text directly works fine. Any Suggestions? @Herbie

Comment: Can you share your code? The code I shared is copied directly from my working application cardobot.com/cardy, so I know it works. Unless you see a typo or something.

Comment: Thank you, I figured out the problem using the original idea of converting a curl command to the javascript/ajax. The link also is different than what you have here.

Comment: Thank you! Can you share the correct links? OpenAI has updated their playground since I made this, so maybe their URL has changed  @nightrain

Comment: Why XHR and not just a simple fetch/POST?